# Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_concat_0

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I first converted 2 gifs of same width and height to mp4 using ffmpeg options

```
ffmpeg -i video1.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" video1.mp4
ffmpeg -i video2.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" video2.mp4
```

afterwards I joined with

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex "concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -f MP4 -y video.mp4
```

But I got error

```
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_concat_0
```

with other mp4 in the past joining works so I don't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inputs for concat have no audio but the filter is expecting them because of `a=1`. Change it to `a=0`.

Comment: oh my thanks (rather weird ffmpeg cannot cope with that by herself :))

Comment: It's not a matter of coping. With `a=1`, the user is telling the filter that audio inputs will be present.

Comment: Today I still have problem even with a=0 ? & "ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\test\demo.mp4" -i "C:\Music\music.mp4" -filter_complex "concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" -f MP4 -y "C:\test\demo_music.mp4"

Comment: Thanks for answering it! It didn't make any sense and I was looking for a solution for a long time.